# Snowflake in dBeaver - Display Snowflake only objects (Streams, Tasks, etc)

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, dbeaver

Anyone coding in snowflake and using dBeaver.  There anyway to show streams, tasks, pipelines ,etc?
I created a stream on table and object explorer doesn't show it.
[image: example]

Comment: I think DBeaver will not display certain object types - other than the standard ones. It's built on Eclipse, so it could probably be written as a plugin (I could help anyone who's interested in writing one).